# Why g++ 8.x fails to compile this code? (SFINAE doesn't work as expected)

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

(I apologize for the title, but I couldn't come up with anything more descriptive)

[This code](https://godbolt.org/z/qU1CJH) fails to compile in g++ 8.x, but compiles in every other C++17-capable compiler (including g++ 7.x):

```
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>

template<class... Ts> struct S
{
    template<std::size_t idx> using vtype = 
        std::variant_alternative_t<idx, std::variant<Ts...>>;
    template<bool B, class T = void> using enable_if = std::enable_if_t<B, T>;
    template<class T, class U> static constexpr bool is_same = std::is_same<T, U>::value;

    template<std::size_t idx, enable_if< is_same<vtype<idx>, int>>...>
    static bool foo() { return true ; }

    template<std::size_t idx, enable_if<!is_same<vtype<idx>, int>>...>
    static bool foo() { return false; }
};

auto x = S<int, char, float>::foo<1>();
```

Why it fails to compile?

(I assume workaround would be to replace SFINAE+overloading with `if constexpr`)

Comment: as it works in 7.4 and trunk its likely just a bug

Comment: @AlanBirtles what's a "trunk" -- latest version?

Comment: yes, trunk is a term in source control, similar to master

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you. Nevermind then, I'll delete the question

Comment: @C.M. Please don't.

Comment: @Barry OK, I'll leave it